# How to return two different values depending on the argument values in Moq method setup?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a test where at some point two lists are compared.

```
IsEqual(List<string> a, List<string> b, ComparisonConfig conf)
```

The above function returns *true* result if List A equals List B
and *false* result otherwise.

In tests I need to setup this function so it returns correct outcome when its called.

```
_service
    .Setup(x => x.IsEqual(It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), null))
    .Returns(Result.Ok(true));
```

for now this always returns true even though lists are not equal.

So the question is how can I make this setup return `Result.Ok(true)` when arguments are equal and `Result.Ok(false)` otherwise.

Comment: capture the arguments in the returns delegate and perform your logic there.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: what type is `conf` as shown in the example provided?

Comment: ComparisonConfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Returns`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods) has several overloads accepting `Func`'s with different number of parameters so it is possible to access invocation arguments when returning a value:

```cs
_service.Setup(x => x.IsEqual(It.IsAny<List<string>>(), It.IsAny<List<string>>(), null))
    .Returns((List<string> l1, List<string> l2, ComparisonConfig c) => 
    {
        if(...) // some logic with l1 and l2
        {
            return Result.Ok(true);
        }
        return Result.Ok(false);
    });
```

The delegate used by `Returns` should match the signature and return type of the member being setup.